# Does SAX Parser keeps all data in Memory?

Tags: java, sax

I'm working on one requirement, Where I need to split big XML and process further.

Here is XML Sample, It can come into Single Line.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><company><staff><firstname>yong</firstname><firstname>jin</firstname></staff></company>
```

And Here is My Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ReadXML {

   public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

    boolean bfname = false;
    boolean blname = false;
    boolean bnname = false;
    boolean bsalary = false;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        System.out.println("Parameters :" + uri +":"+ localName +":"+ qName +":"+ attributes);
        System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")) {
            bfname = true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LASTNAME")) {
            blname = true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("NICKNAME")) {
            bnname = true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SALARY")) {
            bsalary = true;
        }

    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {

        System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        System.out.println("Im here:"+Arrays.toString(ch));----Line 1
        if (bfname) {
            System.out.println("First Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            bfname = false;
        }

        if (blname) {
            System.out.println("Last Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            blname = false;
        }

        if (bnname) {
            System.out.println("Nick Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            bnname = false;
        }

        if (bsalary) {
            System.out.println("Salary : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            bsalary = false;
        }

    }

     };

       saxParser.parse("C:\\Lenny\\Work\\XML\\SaxParsing_01.xml", handler);



        /*InputSource input = new InputSource("C:\\Lenny\\Work\\XML\\SaxParsing_01.xml");
        System.out.println(input);
        XMLReader reader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
        reader.parse(input);*/


     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

   }

}
```

My First Doubt is, Does SAXParser reads bytes wise ?

Second, I want my output like this.

```
<firstname>yong</firstname>
<firstname>jin</firstname>
```

This thing I can manage, But want to know..the moment I get `<firstname>` tag and goes into `characters` method, Why its printing All whole XML ? Shouldn't it print `yong` only at `Line 1` rather than printing whole XML ? Its printing all, So that's why am thinking, DOES `SAXParser` keep whole data in memory or not ?

Any Suggestions please..!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Does SAX Parser keeps all data in Memory?

No, that's the point. It's much easier to load an XML's document whole DOM data in memory, then extract what you want from it, than to use SAX cumbersome model.

But SAX comes with the benefits of reading the document on the fly, without loading it entirely in memory.

> My First Doubt is, Does SAXParser reads bytes wise ?

Not bytewise, no. That would be awfully inefficient, especially considering the very point of SAX is to operate on enormous documents. It is a buffered read. Not that that would consume much memory.

> Why its printing All whole XML ? Shouldn't it print yong only at Line
>   1 rather than printing whole XML ? Its printing all, So that's why am
>   thinking, DOES SAXParser keep whole data in memory or not ?

See above, for sane performances reasons, SAX uses a buffer to read. The char[] given as parameter to the characters() method, is roughly the aforementioned buffer.

In your example, your document is tiny, and of course it will fit entirely in a real-world buffer meant to read a document.
If you were to work with bigger documents, you'll notice that the buffer contains thousands of characters, but nowhere near the entire document.

Comment: So If my one xml which come in single line is having a size of 1+GB, Could be failed ....right...? Because SAXParser I guess reads whole line and puts into memory and then makes the call to check the tags...Correct ?

Comment: @Lenny no... It doesn't read lines. It reads a buffer. It depends on the implementation but it reads, like, 1000 bytes, then decodes them to characters and puts them in a char buffer.